# Sharing old data in addthis plugin instead sharing new updated data

Tags: php, social-networking, sharing, meta, addthis

```
<a href="http://www.addthis com/bookmark.php" class="addthis_button" addthis:url="http://abc/abcd.php?id=<?php echo $row['item_id']; ?>" addthis:title="<?php echo $row['item_name']; ?>" addthis:description="<?php echo $row['item_description']; ?>"></a>
```

I'm using this url to share on social n/w's, all are working fine,
If i share it on social's like facebook, it works well, but if second time i made any changes in item name or description then it shares old data instead of sharing new updated data.

```
<!-- Facebook Share Components -->
<meta property="fb:app_id"      content="111111111" />
<meta property="og:image"       content="<?php echo $img_path;?>"/>
<meta property="og:title"       content="www.abc com"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $itemDetail['item_description'];?>"/>
<meta property="og:url"         content="http://abc com/abcd.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['item_id'];?>"/>
<meta property="og:site_name"   content="abc"/>
<meta property="og:type"        content="website"/>
```

How to clear old data from facebook or from other social's after sharing? I think it's storing that data in cookies or whatever it is.

Here I give space near dot in dot com(cz not allowed)

Comment: `http://abc/`, `http://www.addthis com/`, `www.abc com`, `http://abc com/` ... that's 4 different broken domains... please use valid syntax in your examples, using example.com, example.net, example.org, example.edu, *.example, ...

Answer (score 0):

It's not being stored in a cookie, it's actually being stored by Facebook.  There's no way to programmatically force FB to re-scrape your page.  You can use the following to tell FB to re-scrape your page, but I don't think it's possible to do after a share.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object

Why do you need to update the values after each share?

Comment: when i shared something, then i realized some changes in item to share, then of course i need to update that item